# Crashlytics hide which files

Tags: android, intellij-idea, crashlytics

It seems like Crashlytics makes these changes:

1. Adds this to android manifest file:

< meta-data android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey" android:value="adasdadadad"/ >

2. Creates `crashlytics.properties` file in root folder.
3. Creates `crashlytics-build.properties` file in assets folder.

It seems like 1 is ok, no problem.

- a) But as far as I understand, I should hide number 2 and number 3 from my apk files ?

I use Intellij 13 and I added `crashlytics.properties` to [compiler excluded files](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/compiler-excludes.html)

- b) When I create signed apk file, it seems like `crashlytics-build.properties` is created in assets folder, and it is packed into apk file. But after apk file creation, it is deleted automatically. I added `crashlytics-build.properties` path to Compiler excludes, but it seems like apk file's assets folder has this file. Should I hide `crashlytics-build.properties` file ? If so how can I do that with Intellij 13 ?

Comment: did you find any way to not include the file in the assets folder?